# Has anyone successfully connected Geogig to an Oracle Database?

Tags: gis, geospatial, oracle-spatial

The Geogig (formerly Geogit) documents [here](http://geogig.org/docs/data/import.html)  specify that it can connect to an Oracle Database, but I am having trouble doing so.  I am using geogig on Ubuntu 14.04  My attempt to connect and the response is below.

```
cfrugard@xxxxx:~/geogig/osp$ geogig oracle list --host nyorapdb02 --port xxxx --database xxxx --user xxxx --password xxxx --schema xxxx 
Error validating the database connection
```

Comment: It would be nice if it showed you how it was actually connecting, wouldn't it. I doubt the `--schema` flag is useful for Oracle though? And it might be picky about SID vs. service name. But I'm entirely guessing.

Comment: Yes.  I've tried with and without schema.  I have tried on SQL Server now too, and getting the same "Error validating the database connection".  Wondering if this is simply an issue working in Ubuntu.  I see most of the examples and screenshots they use are on Windows.  I didn't think it would be, since think it's using JDBC for connection.

Comment: Those issues can be frustrating, especially with all those simple-minded tools that do not show any details about what exactly fails and only say "does not work".  The error could have many causes: it could come from the client setup, or from the server.

Comment: My approach to debugging is to first remove the tool from the equation, i.e. confirm that I can connect using a simple client tool (sqlplus). Before that, do some simple checks: does your client know about "nyorapdb02" as a DNS name - or does it need a fully qualified name ? Can you ping the server ? Is the listener up and running on the server ? Does it really listen on port 1521 (or whatever port you specify) ? Is the database up and running and does the TNS listener know about it ? Do you specify the proper database service name (or SID ?) ?

Comment: The ultimate test is to connect using a basic tools (sqlplus for Oracle). Best is to ask for assistance from your DBA who can help you with those tests. If that works, then the issue is clearly with Geogig. Tracing the sqlnet connection can help find out what happens. Again your DBA can help you diagnose.

Comment: Oh, and of course, since Geogig happens to be java, you obviously need to have the proper JDBC driver on your class path. You have of course done that ?

Comment: I believe the java libraries necessary are all in the "repo" directory for the application.  If I look at the script that launches the app, I can see this (could be wrong, this might be a bit over my head)

Comment: if [ -z "$REPO" ]
then
  REPO="$BASEDIR"/repo
fi

CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH_PREFIX:"$BASEDIR"/etc:"$REPO"/*

Comment: Also, I can connect to the database using SQL Developer as well as a Rails App I am using.

Comment: I attempted to run the program after renaming the "repo" directory, just to make sure it was using that, and it will not load, so it seems to be finding those files correctly.

Comment: "Error: Could not find or load main class org.locationtech.geogig.cli.GeogigCLI" after renaming the repo directory.

Comment: gt-jdbc-oracle-11.2.jar                    py4j-0.8.1.jar
gt-jdbc-postgis-11.2.jar                   servlet-api-2.4.jar
gt-jdbc-spatialite-11.2.jar                servlet-api-2.5-6.1.5.jar
gt-jdbc-sqlserver-11.2.jar  are contained in that directory, so I am assuming those are the ones the application expects to use.  I was able to test on a PG database, and that actually worked.  Just not working for Oracle (and SQL Server) even though the docs seem to indicate it should.

Comment: <facepalm>I went and added other JDBC jars I had to the repo directory, and I am now connecting</facepalm>.  Sweet!  can you post that as an answer so I can accept?